# Separar una cadena/string usando un delimitador en c#

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta es basicamente como puedo separar una cadena usando un delimitador. En mi caso lo que hice fue separarlo usando un split, digamos la cadena contrendrá lo siguiente:

```
ADELIMITADORB
```

Pero lo que obtengo al separarlo es `DELIMITADORB` cuando lo que queria obtener era `A Y B`. Resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Source:

```
using System;

namespace Consol
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // TODO: Implement Functionality Here
            //obtenemos la string
            string str = "AdelimitadorB";

            char[] delimiterChars = { 'D', 'E', 'L', 'I', 'M' , 'I', 'T', 'A', 'D', 'O', 'R'};

            string[] arr = str.Split(delimiterChars);

            string a = arr[0];
            string b = arr[1];

            Console.Write(b);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Como podría hacer para obtener `A Y B` por separado usando el delimitador `DELIMITADOR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con tu código que es que estas usando los delimitadores en mayusculas y que usas caracteres sueltos en lugar de una palabra. Prueba esto:

```
string str = "AdelimitadorB"; 
string[] arr=str.Split(new string[] { "delimitador" }, 
                                                StringSplitOptions.None);
string a = arr[0];
string b = arr[1];
```

Si insistes en definir tu delimitador separando las letras como lo haces, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { 'd', 'e', 'l', 'i', 'm', 'i', 't', 'a', 'd', 'o', 'r' };
string[] arr=str.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Aunque esto en realidad no te hace el split por la palabra completa, si no cada vez que te va a separar cada vez que encuentre uno de los caracteres de la palabra.

De todas maneras, no te recomiendo usar toda una palabra como delimitador,si no un sólo caracter

Comment: Ya pero esque el carácter se podrá repetir por eso quería hacerlo con un delimitador. O sino trabajar con byte array's pero eso ya sería otra pregunta diferente.

Comment: @OmarOmar Normalmente yo siempre uso algun carácter extraño que sea casi imposible que se repita, como `あ`. Dudo que te vayas a encontrar algo asi normalmente no? :)

Comment: @Pikoh [私は日本語が理解できません](https://translate.google.com/?hl=es#auto/es/%E7%A7%81%E3%81%AF%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E7%90%86%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)

Comment: Yo tampoco @lois6b :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar esta solución que he encontrado en: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928601/how-can-i-split-a-string-with-a-string-delimiter)

```
string[] arr = str.Split(new[] { "delimitador" },StringSplitOptions.None);
```